# try to insert data into two tables with the same instructions not working

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi I am trying to insert data into two tables with the same instructions but still not getting it right the data goes to table one and not table two

this is my code

```
$putData = "INSERT INTO project_info       (id, pro_title, pro_address, pro_area_from, pro_area_to, pro_kind, pro_description, pro_finish, pro_big_rooms, pro_small_rooms, pro_reception, pro_big_bathroom, pro_small_bathroom, propActivity, yb, map) values ( '', '$pro_name', '$pro_address', '$area_from', '$area_to', '$pro_kind', '$pro_description', '$pro_finish', '$pro_big_rooms', '$pro_small_rooms', '$pro_receptions', '$pro_big_bathrooms', '$pro_small_bathrooms', '$proActivity', '$pro_yb', '$googleMap')";    
$putData = "INSERT INTO project_info_arabic(id, pro_title, pro_address, pro_area_from, pro_area_to, pro_kind, pro_description, pro_finish, pro_big_rooms, pro_small_rooms, pro_reception, pro_big_bathroom, pro_small_bathroom, propActivity, yb, map) values ( '', '$pro_name', '$pro_address', '$area_from', '$area_to', '$pro_kind', '$pro_description', '$pro_finish', '$pro_big_rooms', '$pro_small_rooms', '$pro_receptions', '$pro_big_bathrooms', '$pro_small_bathrooms', '$proActivity', '$pro_yb', '$googleMap')";
$result = mysqli_multi_query($db, $putData)or die( $db->error );
```

the data go to project_info_arabic and not project_info
what I did wrong here

Comment: Have you checked if the 2nd table has all the fields you indicate? Try manually executing the `INSERT INTO project_info_arabic` and see what is going wrong.

Comment: yes I just did and all have the same fields

Comment: There needs to be a semi-colon at the end of each query. IE "SELECT * FROM TABLE; SELECT id FROM TABLE2"

Comment: @Rottingham sorry I didn't get what you mean I am not selecting I am inserting and there is semi-colon at the end

Comment: you needed two queries to concated as one query.

Comment: @Awlad Liton yes if it's possible

Comment: @Yousef Altaf : I have posted an answer try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**mysqli_multi_query** Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon.

```
$putData="INSERT INTO project_info(id, pro_title, pro_address, pro_area_from, pro_area_to, pro_kind, pro_description, pro_finish, pro_big_rooms, pro_small_rooms, pro_reception, pro_big_bathroom, pro_small_bathroom, propActivity, yb, map) values ( '', '$pro_name', '$pro_address', '$area_from', '$area_to', '$pro_kind', '$pro_description', '$pro_finish', '$pro_big_rooms', '$pro_small_rooms', '$pro_receptions', '$pro_big_bathrooms', '$pro_small_bathrooms', '$proActivity', '$pro_yb', '$googleMap')";
//i have concatenated query with semicolon
$putData.=";"."INSERT INTO project_info_arabic(id, pro_title, pro_address, pro_area_from, pro_area_to, pro_kind, pro_description, pro_finish, pro_big_rooms, pro_small_rooms, pro_reception, pro_big_bathroom, pro_small_bathroom, propActivity, yb, map) values ( '', '$pro_name', '$pro_address', '$area_from', '$area_to', '$pro_kind', '$pro_description', '$pro_finish', '$pro_big_rooms', '$pro_small_rooms', '$pro_receptions', '$pro_big_bathrooms', '$pro_small_bathrooms', '$proActivity', '$pro_yb', '$googleMap')";

 $result=mysqli_multi_query($db, $putData)or die( $db->error );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$putData = "INSERT INTO project_info       (id, pro_title, pro_address, pro_area_from, pro_area_to, pro_kind, pro_description, pro_finish, pro_big_rooms, pro_small_rooms, pro_reception, pro_big_bathroom, pro_small_bathroom, propActivity, yb, map) values ( '', '$pro_name', '$pro_address', '$area_from', '$area_to', '$pro_kind', '$pro_description', '$pro_finish', '$pro_big_rooms', '$pro_small_rooms', '$pro_receptions', '$pro_big_bathrooms', '$pro_small_bathrooms', '$proActivity', '$pro_yb', '$googleMap');";    
$putData .= "INSERT INTO project_info_arabic(id, pro_title, pro_address, pro_area_from, pro_area_to, pro_kind, pro_description, pro_finish, pro_big_rooms, pro_small_rooms, pro_reception, pro_big_bathroom, pro_small_bathroom, propActivity, yb, map) values ( '', '$pro_name', '$pro_address', '$area_from', '$area_to', '$pro_kind', '$pro_description', '$pro_finish', '$pro_big_rooms', '$pro_small_rooms', '$pro_receptions', '$pro_big_bathrooms', '$pro_small_bathrooms', '$proActivity', '$pro_yb', '$googleMap')";
$result = mysqli_multi_query($db, $putData)or die( $db->error );
```

**Notice**
You did not concated your query with semicolon( http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php ) so you have assigned twice in $putData. It is overwrite your previous query and hold the latest query. So Its only inserted data in second table not in the first table.

Comment: @Yousef Altaf : do you understand now why its inserted data in the second table only?